# how to save blob object in rails using paperclip. after editing a image i get blob object.how can i save it in my rails Db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
<%= f.hidden_field :document, :id=>"base64", :value=>"", :name=>"base64"  %> 
<%= f.submit "SAVE",  :class=>"c-btn-green-light", :type=>"submit", :id=>"save_canvas", :onclick=>"dataObject()" %>
```

Here, I am getting blob object after click save button

I want to send the blob object in a hidden field

Comment: Have you tried reading the object as file?

Comment: no I want to read the blob object and then want to save this file . am using paperclip to upload file.

Comment: No matter what you're using to upload the file, you have to read the file and then take the data and insert it as blob. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to have column type as binary and you can directly assign blob object to that column.
e.g

obj.data = params[:document].read

Here is rails documentation for creating  column with binary type. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column